# SFML 2.1 Copying Images

Tags: c++, sfml, member

I'm following a tilemap tutorial which uses SFML 2.0, but I have 2.1 on my computer. Naturally, this creates some issues. Here, the tutorial is trying to copy a tile's image for the tilemap (I think?) but the conversion to 2.1 lingo is difficult.

```
//Copy the right tile image from tileset
        sf::Texture tileImage;
        tileImage.create(tileSize, tileSize);
        tileImage.Copy(tileset, 0, 0, sf::IntRect(x * tileSize, y * tileSize, frames * tileSize, tileSize), true);
```

"Copy" is underlined, saying `sf::texture has no member "Copy"` I get that. What I don't get is how to do what he is trying to do in SFML 2.1, which is annoyingly different. Cany anybody tell me what member of Texture in 2.1 would work for this issue?

Comment: Maybe it's [sf::Texture::loadFromImage](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1Texture.php#abec4567ad9856a3596dc74803f26fba2) you want?

Comment: Is that the actual code? Are you sure `tileImage` isn't a `sf::Image`?

Answer (score 2):

SFML uses camelCase, so the function should start with a lowercase letter.

Then, `sf::Texture` indeed has no `copy` method but `sf::Image` has. Depending on what you're doing you might need to change the type of `tileImage` or you might want to use `sf::Texture::loadFromImage` instead.